# Alterar máscara do RG

Tags: javascript

A máscara do RG vem com um padrão diferente no qual eu necessito!

Código do RG:

```
function Rg(v){
        v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");                                     
        v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1.$2");             
        v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1.$2");   
        v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d)$/,"$1-$2");              
      return v
}
```

nesse código ele joga o RG com o padrão: `88888.888-8`

E o padrão que eu preciso é : `88.888.888-8`

Obrigado pelas demais respostas. E gostaria de adicionar uma pergunta:

*"Tem como utilizar um `if` na hora da digitação para verificar o tanto de numeros informados para padronizar na função?"*

Comment: Olá, olha esse link ele mostra um masked input exatamente do jeito que voce precisa. [Masked Input](http://www.chrdesigner.com/mascara-personalizada-jquery-oito-nove-digitos/#arvlbdata)

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, mas isso não é exatamente o que eu preciso!

Comment: Cara, não sei por que você quer neste formato, mas... A quantidade de números do RG varia, tem estado que tem mais e menos números, dependendo de onde é a pessoa, pode ser que não se adapte a esta quantia de números que você quer checar.

Comment: É cara ... O problema é que, quando você é "peão" você deve obedecer quando lhe passam uma coisa!

Comment: E esse aqui: http://www.duocriativa.com.br/janela/blog/2012/06/10/aplicando-mascaras-a-campos-de-formularios-com-plugin-jquery

Comment: Sei, mas no caso, complete com zeros á esquerda, total pode ter até 9 mesmo.

Comment: Pergunta repetida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22431/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-rg

Answer (score 3):

Em JavaScript puro e sem validação alguma, o código da função deve ficar assim:

```
function Rg(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})$/,"$1.$2.$3-$4");
    return v;
}
```

Preparei um exemplo com verificação de erros para você verificar se é isso que precisa. A função só sabe trabalhar com argumentos de exatamente 9 dígitos, ou seja, funciona mais ou menos como o código que você já tinha.

http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/667Bw/1/

Respondendo à sua segunda pergunta: sim, é possível verificar a entrada do usuário, inclusive há mais de uma maneira de fazer isso.

Neste exemplo acima, eu utilizei o `if` dentro da função `Rg()`, e comunico o erro de digitação através de uma Exception; outra implementação seria a pré-validação dentro da função de callback `imprimeFormatado()`, evitando a chamada da função `Rg()` (através de um `if`) caso o número de dígitos esteja incorreto. Porém, se a função `Rg()` é chamada em mais de um local, recomendo implementá-la como eu fiz.

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o maskedinput-1.3.js(JQuery) olha o exemplo abaixo:
Obs: é preciso verificar o caminho dos arquvos .js e corrigi-lo se for necessário. Abaixo exemplos de como definir as máscaras para diversos tipos de entrada.

```
<head>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    // ...

</head><br/>


<form><br/>
       Telefone: <input type="text" id="telefone" /<br/>
       CEP:      <input type="text" id="cep" /><br/>
       Data:     <input type="text" id="data" /><br/>
       CNPJ:     <input type="text" id="cnpj" /><br/>
       RG:       <input type="text" id="rg" /><br/>
       Agência:  <input type="text" id="agencia" /><br/>
       Comta:    <input type="text" id="conta" /><br/>
</form><br/>

<script type="text/javascript"><br/>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {<br/>

            $("#telefone").mask("(99) 9999-9999");     // Máscara para TELEFONE

            $("#cep").mask("99999-999");    // Máscara para CEP

            $("#data").mask("99/99/9999");    // Máscara para DATA

            $("#cnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");    // Máscara para CNPJ

            $('#rg').mask('99.999.999-9');    // Máscara para RG<br/>

            $('#agencia').mask('9999-9');    // Máscara para AGÊNCIA BANCÁRIA

            $('#conta').mask('99.999-9');    // Máscara para CONTA BANCÁRIA

    }); <br/>

</script><br/>
```

link da biblioteca para download: [maskedinput-1.3.js](https://cloud.github.com/downloads/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js)

Comment: É exatamente o link que eu coloquei no comentário

Comment: ah beleza, desculpa aew! Eu uso esse tbm!

Comment: @RogersCorrêa eu editei seu código mas não tenho certeza se ele têm tags desnecessárias. Agora que ele já está em formato de código, poderia fazer os ajustes necessários?