# Expressão Regular para RG

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma `expressão regular` que define os pontos conforme o número máximo de dígitos.

Expressão:

```
function Rg(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    if(v.length == 9) v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})$/,"$1.$2.$3-$4");
    return v
}
```

`RG :` `88.888.888-8`

Mas gostaria de uma expressão que padronize com diferentes dígitos. Exemplo:

`RG :` `8.888.888-8`

Sem a utilização de outro `if` como o exemplo a seguir:

```
function Rg(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    if(v.length == 9) v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})$/,"$1.$2.$3-$4");
    if(v.length == 8) v=v.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})$/,"$1.$2.$3-$4"); 
    return v
}
```

É possível?

Comment: essa regra não se aplica a todos os estados. Em Minas Gerais tem RGs com o formato `MG-14.808.688`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Amigo, aqui está, não esqueça de reputar quem te ajuda ao invés de fazer outras perguntas e esquecer as respostas. Ajuda toda a comunidade! ;)

```
function Rg(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,""); //Substituí o que não é dígito por "", /g é [Global][1]
    v=v.replace(/(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1})$/,"$1.$2.$3-$4"); 
    // \d{1,2} = Separa 1 grupo de 1 ou 2 carac. (\d{3}) = Separa 1 grupo de 3 carac. (\d{1}) = Separa o grupo de 1 carac.
    // "$1.$2.$3-$4" = recupera os grupos e adiciona "." após cada.

        return v
    }
```

Exemplo com função[MSDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
function styleHyphenFormat(propertyName)
{
  function upperToHyphenLower(match)
  {
    return '-' + match.toLowerCase();
  }
  return propertyName.replace(/[A-Z]/g, upperToHyphenLower);
}
```

Comment: Foi erro na hora, pois já havia feito aquela com o if, por isso acabei deletando para mudar a pergunta!

Comment: Bah cara, queria manjar assim de Regex! Boa Rony! :D

Comment: Você poderia explicar o que exatamente cada parte da sua expressão faz.

Comment: @Ronny Amarante por curiosidade de universitário, se caso o `RG` fosse `888.888-8` a expressão seria como?

Comment: @Kazzkiq, adicionei algumas explicações, espero conseguir expressar bem o que cada coisa faz.

Comment: @Felipe: o ideal seria você passar no lugar do "$1.$2 etc.." uma função, pois, ele sempre irá retornar "*.*000.000-0" usando esse exemplo... Com função você poderá formatar melhor. Deixarei um exemplo com função.

Comment: @Ronny Amarante Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui fazer o que eu queria!

Comment: Esse regex admite que o dígito verificador do RG só pode ser um número, sendo que na realidade pode ser X também. Precisa mudar `\d{1}` para `[\dX]`.

Answer (score 2):

### MAIS CORRETO

Já estava quase bom na resposta  do @RonnyAmarante, mas conforme comentários, esqueceu do "X"... Como nem sempre dá para tratar dos erros, aqui inclui o parâmetro `errChar` só para lembrar ou não com "?" de que tem algo estranho no RG.

```js
function RgFormat(v0,errChar='?'){
    var v = v0.toUpperCase().replace(/[^\dX]/g,'');
    return (v.length==8 || v.length==9)?
       v.replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{3})([\dX])$/,'$1.$2.$3-$4'):
       (errChar+v0)
    ;
}
```

NOTA: como aceita inicio com 1 ou 2 dígitos (poderia também preencher com zero), é importante o `^` para integralidade no caso de 2 dígitos.

... Já que falamos em mensagem de erro, resta validar o dígito verificador (`$4`), vide pergunta [Validação de RG](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71/4186) ou [esta explicação didática](http://www.ngmatematica.com/2014/02/como-determinar-o-digito-verificador-do.html).