# JQuery - máscara de RG

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tendo problemas ao criar uma máscara com JQuery, pois existem rg's que se encerram com o digito 'X'.

HTML

```
<input name="rg" class="form-control" id="rg" pattern="^(d{3}\.d{3}\.d{3}\-d{2}" max='11'>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rg").mask("999.999.999-99" || "999.999.999-a");});  
</script>
```

Não consigo colocar a condição 'ou', para aceitar mais de uma máscara como alternativa.

Comment: Impossível o CPF terminar em dígito. Você deve estar confundindo com alguns R.G. Pela fórmula do CPF, só são aceitos números.

Comment: é RG mesmo cara...

Comment: O RG muda de formato em cada estado. Não é simples assim. Teria que montar várias combinações.

Comment: É máscara de CPF ou RG?

Comment: É mascara de RG

Comment: RG, por uma gama de motivos, normalmente não tem máscara. O que realmente se usa é uma expressão para formatação, dependendo da digitação.
Sua resposta, como o @Bacco disse, é respondida neste link: [Expressão Regular para RG](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22431/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-rg)